# how to change variable value in jenkins pipeline stage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I declared a variable in environment block in jenkins pipeline with default value='null' and trying to change the value in a stage.

But the result is immutable.

```
pipeline
   { 
    agent any
 environment {
        buildResult = 'null'
    }
    stages{

           stage('Build Using Maven') {
              steps{
                        echo env.buildResult
                        script
                        {
                            env.buildResult = "FALIURE"
                        }
                            echo env.buildResult
                          notifyBuild('STARTED')
                          withMaven(maven : 'maven'){
                          sh '''
                          mvn clean install -DskipTests
                          cd project_pom/pom_espo_bdd_tests
                          mvn test
                          '''

                }
```

Comment: Do you really need to use *environment variable* and not regular (global) variable?

Comment: You are changing the environment variable in specific stage which will remain for that stage only.



For further steps the environment will be same as you declared in to environment{} block.

Comment: Sure with that statement?